# How to obtain class labels of xgboost predictions?

Tags: r, xgboost

I am using xgboost similar to the following example, where I "recode" some numeric value to a (numeric) value in 0,1,2 indicating class labels. Note that I did not convert this to a factor variable.

Then I use xgboost to fit a model and produce predictions.

```
library(xgboost)

iris$Species <- runif(nrow(iris))

recode <- function(x){
  if(x >= 0 & x <= 0.33){
    x <- 0
  } else if(x > 0.33 & x <= 0.66){
    x <- 1
  } else if(x > 0.66){
    x <- 2
  }
} 

train <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(iris[,-5]), 
                     label = sapply(iris$Species, FUN = recode))

bst <- xgboost(data = train,
               max_depth = 4, eta = 0.5, nrounds = 10, 
               objective = "multi:softprob",
               num_class = 3)

pred <- predict(bst, as.matrix(iris[, -5]), reshape = TRUE)

str(pred)
```

Is there away to obtain the column labels of the matrix of predictions? Or can I be sure that they are ordered according to the numeric values to which I recoded the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns follow the same order as your label, so it's 0,1 and 2. To be sure, you can do a confusion matrix to check whether you are predicting it correctly:

```
library(xgboost)
set.seed(100)
iris$Species <- runif(nrow(iris))

train <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(iris[,-5]), 
                     label = sapply(iris$Species, FUN = recode))

bst <- xgboost(data = train,
               max_depth = 4, eta = 0.5, nrounds = 10, 
               objective = "multi:softprob",
               num_class = 3)

pred <- predict(bst, as.matrix(iris[, -5]), reshape = TRUE)
# which.max tells you which column is most probable
# we convert them back to 0-2, assuming column 1 corresponds to 0
predicted = apply(pred,1,which.max)-1
actual = sapply(iris$Species,recode)
table(predicted,actual)
```

The results are:

```
     actual
predicted  0  1  2
        0 36  2  2
        1  4 48  4
        2  6  3 45
```

So most of those predicted to be 0,1 or 2 follows the highest probable class predicted.

Or if you use caret:

```
caret::confusionMatrix(factor(predicted,levels=1:3),factor(actual,levels=1:3))
```

Comment: This is what I had expected, but I was wondering because I didn't find specific information in the documentation on this. The use of a confusion matrix is a good idea!

Comment: yes xgboost sux a bit with the numerical encoding. Hope this helps you :)